# Time for [wake-up] to go back to [sleep]

Tags: discussion, tag-synonym-request

The tag [wake-up](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/wake-up) is used mainly to describe the process of waking up from [sleep](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/sleep).

I think that the process of system sleep/wake-up are too similar, (and ultimately about the same process) to warrant having separate tags for both, thus I suggest we synonimise [wake-up](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/wake-up) into [sleep](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/sleep).

Thoughts?

Comment: Go one better, how about [sleep-hibernation], which would include returning to action?  Is there enough difference between sleep and hibernation that warrants both, and would the "ambiguity" be meaningful?

Comment: @fixer1234 I feel like the sleep vs hibernation can of worms isn't something we want to get into.

Comment: @fixer1234 - Whilst I agree that sleep states vs hibernation are pretty similar and could probably be lumped together, I, like Raystafarian feel a lot of people wouldn't be happy with that either, as they *are* two completely separate processes executed in different ways.

Comment: I think they should both be kept. [sleep] has 722 questions so its a a point where it can afford sub-categories, and [wake-up] has 89 questions which suggests people are finding it a useful subcategory. I don't see the benefit of taking a step back, and making these questions harder to find among the hundreds of [sleep] questions. PS: Love the title btw.